# MySql Upsert Proc That Only Updates If Values Passed

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create an upsert proc, but if it will be an update I want to have the ability to only send the fields that are changing. Is this possible?

Below is a slimmed down version of my proc.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE pr_upsertImage (_id int(11), _src varchar(150), _pixelWidth int(11), _pixelHeight int(11))
BEGIN
            
      REPLACE INTO image
        (id, src, pixelWidth, pixelHeight)
           VALUES 
        (COALESCE(_id, id), COALESCE(_src, src), COALESCE(_pixelWidth, pixelWidth), COALESCE(_pixelHeight, pixelHeight));
            
      SELECT
        id,
        src,
        pixelWidth,
        pixelHeight
      FROM image WHERE id = IFNULL(_id, LAST_INSERT_ID());
 END;
```

For example I only want to send the id, pixelHeight and pixelWidth because the record already contains the id and the src.

I thought I could do it with COALESCE but it keeps updating the record with null fields.

Answer (score 0):

You copied the code form some website that really doesn't work in mysql
But the problem is easily fixed
You have to drop the procedure and can't use O REPLACE, that isn't allowed in MySQL

> ```
> CREATE TABLE image (id BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT
> , src varchar(150), pixelWidth BIGINT, pixelHeight BIGINT,
>   PRIMARY KEY (id));
> ```

> ```
> DROP PROCEDURE IF EXisTS pr_upsertImage;
> CREATE  PROCEDURE pr_upsertImage 
> (_id int(11), _src varchar(150), _pixelWidth int(11), _pixelHeight int(11))
> BEGIN
>             
>       REPLACE INTO image
>         (id, src, pixelWidth, pixelHeight)
>            VALUES 
>         (COALESCE(_id, id), COALESCE(_src, src), COALESCE(_pixelWidth, pixelWidth), COALESCE(_pixelHeight, pixelHeight));
>             
>       SELECT
>         id,
>         src,
>         pixelWidth,
>         pixelHeight
>       FROM image WHERE id = IFNULL(_id, LAST_INSERT_ID());
>  END
> ```

> ```
> call pr_upsertImage (1,'test',10,10)
> ```
>
> ```
> id | src  | pixelWidth | pixelHeight
> -: | :--- | ---------: | ----------:
>  1 | test |         10 |          10
>
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> call pr_upsertImage (1,'test2',10,10)
> ```
>
> ```
> id | src   | pixelWidth | pixelHeight
> -: | :---- | ---------: | ----------:
>  1 | test2 |         10 |          10
>
> ✓
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2fb224ee650b49049164686d6e1d8b51)*

Comment: He says that the procedure is updating the record with null values. If the problem were the `CREATE PROCEDURE` syntax it wouldn't run at all.

Comment: yes Barmar, but the cause of that is not to determine, except that there is a problem, which is not there i9m mysql, as he uses .CREATE OR REPLAC o am nt sure, if he has ever enterd any data , so we will wait and see

Comment: Create or Replace does not seem to be an issue. It's actually Mariadb 10 that I am using; so that could be why. I was actually able to solve the problem by removing the option on the _id and changing COALESCE to IFNULL

Comment: @user10012 you can change in  the fiddle between mysql and mariadb and none have problems, , can you update your database to the latest version or at least szbversion.